# Compiling NanoVM Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, compilation, makefile

I have problem with compiling NanoVM project from:

http://www.harbaum.org/till/nanovm/index.shtml

NanoVM is Java implementation for AVR microcontrollers. I know this is not efficient. I have problem with "makefile" file. This makefile contains instructions to compile Java .class from source .java files. But i don't know, how can i run makefile? I was using previously javac.exe compiler to write java standard applications. In install instructions writes that I must have Java SDK (J2SE). Is there any difference between SDK and JDK? I have JDK installed, i have read earlier that there isn't any difference between SDK and JDK, but i'm not sure. I know makefile files are used to manage compilation, i previously used makefile to compile programs wrote in C, but is there some Java compiler like gcc? Sorry for my stupid question, i'm quite newbie in makefiles, i think solution is very simple.
My makefile:

```
#
# Makefile for NanoVMTool
#

APP = NanoVMTool
VERSION = 1.5

all: ../$(APP).jar

CLASSPATH = ../../java/examples
NATIVEPATH = ../../java/native

JAVAFILES = AccessFlags.java CodeInfo.java ConstPoolEntry.java FieldInfo.java \
            MethodInfo.java AttributeInfo.java CodeTranslator.java \
        ConstPoolEntryError.java InnerClassInfo.java NanoVMTool.java \
        ClassFileReader.java CommonInfo.java ConvertException.java \
        LineNumberInfo.java NativeMapper.java ClassInfo.java \
        Config.java Debug.java LocalVariableInfo.java UVMWriter.java \
        ClassLoader.java ConstPool.java ExceptionInfo.java \
        MethodIdTable.java Uploader.java NVMComm2.java

# compile target code
$(CLASSPATH)/%.class: $(CLASSPATH)/%.java
    javac -classpath $(CLASSPATH):$(NATIVEPATH) $<

%.class: %.java
    echo "public class Version {" > Version.java
    echo "  public static String version = \"V$(VERSION)\";" >> Version.java
    echo "}" >> Version.java
    javac $<

../$(APP).jar: $(APP).class
    jar cmf $(APP).mf ../$(APP).jar *.class

# convert and upload a class file (should be moved to vm/target Makefile)
asuro-%: $(CLASSPATH)/%.class $(APP).class
    java $(APP) ../config/Asuro.config $(CLASSPATH) $*

mega8-%: $(CLASSPATH)/%.class $(APP).class
    java  $(APP) ../config/Mega8.config $(CLASSPATH) $*

clean:
    rm -f *.class *~
```

Comment: What is your actual question? How to call `make`?

Comment: Yes i want to run makefile (compile), and i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run a Makefile (on Linux / UNIX), you first need to install "make" and any of the other tools that it uses.  In this case, the tools are just the `java`, `javac` and `jar` commands.  For the last two, you need a JDK installation.

> But i don't know, how can i run makefile?

Change directory to the directory containing the Makefile, then run 'make' with the appropriate target.  In this case `make all`.

> Is there any difference between SDK and JDK?

There is no such thing as the Java SDK.

> ... but is there some Java compiler like gcc?

The Java compiler is `javac`.  That is what your makefile is using.

---

> Sorry for my stupid question, i'm quite newbie in makefiles, i think solution is very simple.

The REAL solution is to find and read a tutorial on Makefiles and how to read, write and use them.  (In general, the solution to asking newbie questions is to educate yourself so that you aren't a newbie!)

Comment: I did it! Thanks for help. I have one question. I had to use command prompt cmd.exe and enter 'make' command in location containing Makefile. But i tried 'make' command earlier on Windows 7 and it failed. How to install make on system?

Comment: I would not recommend that you try to build NanoVMTool on Windows.  The problem is not just installing it.  You also have the problem that Makefiles tend to by operating system dependent.  You would probably need to modify the Makefile too.

Comment: Yes i know, author of project wrote in instruction, that it was build on linux and Makefile must be modified if i want to build this on windows, i have just run 'make' and i had errors.

Comment: By the way, installing software is an off-topic question.